# How can i solve Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reducers' while setting rootReducer in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to configure redux with my react app. While configuring rootReducer I am facing this error:
**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reducers'**

**Here is my code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer })

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my folder structure and files screenshot
https://ibb.co/ZVbLh9S

What am I missing?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no file called `reducers.js`. But you have a `usersSlice.js` - are you taking things from multiple different tutorials here? In that case, please follow only one, from start to end, preferrably the [official tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

As for your problems - assuming this is your `store.js` and your `userSlice.js` contains `export default slice.reducer`, do the following:

```js
import usersReducer from './usersSlice';

// ....


const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: {
    users: usersReducer
  }
})
```